# How to fix error that cause addOnCompleteListener() from starting

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have followed the instruction in android studio to add Firebase Auth to app. the code is adding new users but not showing the toast it suppose to. I have tried to debug the code and seen it tase not entered the method "on complete"
    enter code here

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,  OnCompleteListener<Void> {


private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
   // updateUI(currentUser);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    CreateNewUser();
}
private void CreateNewUser()
{
    //creates a new user and adds it to firebase
    //uses the mail and password in the edit text
    final String TAG="tag";
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("example @gmail.com","1234567")
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Task is successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();


                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

I expected to have a toast saying that "Task is successfull" since it has entered it to the firebase users database

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `onClickListener` for your view which should trigger the `CreateNewUser` method? You `Activity` is implementing the interface. In `onCreate` you should be calling something like:

```
findViewById(R.id.myButton).setOnClickListener(this);
```

Where `myButton` is the id of the `View` defined in your activitys xml.